# Is there a shorter function to use than IFS to reference other columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of students with their classes in column H, and I want to populate column I with the room numbers. I need to do this with a lot of classes and typing them into an IFS function works but it's very tedious.

Currently I have a reference tab with the class names in column A and their room numbers in column B, and this is the function I'm using:

```
=ifs(H2="Pre-K (3-5yr)", Reference!$B$2, H2="My Father's Dragon (3-6yr)", Reference!$B$3, H2="Pre-K (4-5yr)", Reference!$B$4, H2="1st-3rd", Reference!$B$5, H2="American Girl Club (7-12yr)", Reference!$B$6, H2="Book of Quotes (9yr+)", Reference!$B$7, H2="Who's Who (4th+)", Reference!$B$8, H2="Teen (7th+)", Reference!$B$9)
```

How can I shorten this process?

Comment: Instead of `IFS()` I would use `XLOOKUP()` or `VLOOKUP()` function to refer a lookuptable to pull the data. Btw what are you using `Excel` or `Google Sheets`?

Comment: I'm using google sheets

Comment: It will still work, create a table having two columns, one for the lookup value i.e. which is equal to H2 and other one for the value to return when it finds a match for the lookup values. Can you post the google sheet link with edit access to see what you have ?

Comment: Ah, finally, that's what I needed, thank you!! #newbiehere

Comment: Sounds Good, glad you figured it out =)

Comment: somebody post an answer if the question is solved :-)

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya

Comment: @Mark if you wish you can post an answer. Also, its not required as OP has clearly what she needs to do. And there are ample of examples for such post.